# Retrieve an array from parse.com and add the values to a local array (Android)

Tags: android, arrays, android-listview, parse-platform

I have an array column called "Roots" in a user class from parse.com and I want to retrieve the array object from the column and then extract the values (strings) to an array in my application.

```
ParseUser.logInInBackground(user, password, new LogInCallback() {
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        // Hooray! The user is logged in.
                        startMenu();
                        String[] testStringArray = (String[])user.get("Roots");
```

I'm not sure if the last line even works. Even if it does, I'm not sure how to extract the individual elements and set them to a local array that I can call on using an index e.g.

```
String myString = testStringArray[1]
```

Or some such. I have tried a few variations of the above code and I think I am missing something fundamental. Does anyone have an example of how I can accomplish this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an `ArrayList<String>` instead of `String[]`, then you can access it as you would any other ArrayList object.

```
ArrayList<String> testStringArrayList = (ArrayList<String>)user.get("Roots");
String myString = testStringArrayList.get(1);
```

Comment: That was the missing piece thanks. One little change. It gave a syntax error if I used the second line but it was an easy fix to... String myString = testStringArrayList.get(1);

Comment: Fixed. I guess I do need some sleep after all!