# Can't Retrieve Array from Parse User

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-arrayadapter

Hello I am new to Android and Parse.com. I am trying to fetch an array from my `ParseUser` class and set it into a `Spinner`. I have followed [this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590859/retrieve-an-array-from-parse-com-and-add-the-values-to-a-local-array-android) but it doesn't work for me.

I am trying to update `Spinner course` when I select another item in `Spinner faculty_initial` in this code

```
Spinner faculty_initial; //another spinner
Spinner course;
ArrayAdapter<String> courseAdapter;

faculty_initial.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //getting the selected item from the faculty_initial spinner
        selectedInitial = initial.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("username", selectedInitial);
        query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser pu, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    JSONArray arr = pu.getJSONArray("Taken_Courses");
                    ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    synchronized(stringArrayList) {
                        if (arr != null) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                                try {
                                    stringArrayList.add(arr.get(i).toString());
                                } catch (Exception exp) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        courseAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(student_to_faculty.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, stringArrayList);
                        courseAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        course.setAdapter(courseAdapter);
                        Toast.makeText(student_to_faculty.this, " Everything is alright in course spinner ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }//synchronized
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(student_to_faculty.this, "new : " + e.toString() + " ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

But this code gives me

> com.parse.exception: no results found for query.

Answer (score 0):

You have used the wrong query to get a user. You have to use following way to query a single user. Try this and see.

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.whereEqualTo("username", selectedInitial);
query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
  public void done(ParseUser pu, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = (ArrayList<String>)pu.get("Taken_Courses");
                    courseAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(student_to_faculty.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stringArrayList);
                    courseAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    course.setAdapter(courseAdapter);
                    Toast.makeText(student_to_faculty.this, " Everything is alright in course spinner ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(student_to_faculty.this, "new : " + e.toString() + " ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
  }
});
```

The query you have used is, getting a ParseUser for a given objectId of a user. That can be used when you have the objectID of the user you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesnt work either. I am using a JSON Array now. would I post my updated code???

Comment: De Alwis Senevira I have updated my code and attached it above. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you debug and see where the exception causes?

Comment: Could you tell me what is Taken_Courses column is ? what is the data type?

Comment: Taken course column is an Array type column. Where I am storing an array for an user.

Comment: If it is possible by using ParseQueryAdapter then please let me know.